# Действия с BitmapImage

Tags: c#, wpf, bitmap, bitmapimage

Можно такие же действия сделать с BitmapImage?

**1.**

```
image = Image.FromStream(ms, true);
```

**2.**

```
public static void UpdateScreen(ref Image screen, Image newScreen, Rectangle bounds)      
{       
    if (screen == null) screen = new Bitmap(bounds.Width, bounds.Height);

    Graphics g = null;

    try
    {
        g = Graphics.FromImage(screen);
        g.DrawImage(newScreen, bounds);
        g.Flush();
    }
    catch
    {

    }
    finally
    {
        if (g != null) g.Dispose();
    }
}
```

Конвертация из Bitmap в BitmapImage не выход, сильно нагружается процессор, а таких действий очень много.

Answer (score -3):

Используйте класс [WriteableBitmap](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.media.imaging.writeablebitmap(v=vs.110).aspx).